# Dynamic help text display in Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am leveraging the technique discussed [here](http://michaelwelburn.com/2014/01/13/customization-of-salesforce-com-help-text-bubbles-in-visualforce/) in order to use help text display on my Visualforce page because the table is being generated by a custom controller and is not in a pageBlockSection.

EDIT - I have a wrapper as a custom controller which 'mocks' the opportunity object and a custom object. The helptext values which I would like are to be varied and random - they aren't stored anywhere in my Org. It's not like referencing a standard/custom field in a Visualforce page which has the helptext field populated which can then be referenced in a pageBlockSection. I'd like the helptext values to be different per row.

The relevant snippet of code in the Visualforce page is:

```
<apex:actionRegion >
        <apex:pageMessage escape="false" summary=" <style> body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS', font-size: 20; } </style> <b>Test 123." severity="INFO" strength="3"></apex:pageMessage>             

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrappers}" var="wrapper" id="wtable">

                <apex:column headerValue="Team">

                    <apex:outputField value="{!wrapper.acrX.Asset_Class__c}" /> 

                    <span class="helpButton" id="example-title-_help">
                        <img src="/s.gif" class="helpOrb"/>
                        Example Text
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        sfdcPage.setHelp('example-title', 'This is where you put the help text');
                        </script>
                    </span>

                </apex:column>


                <!-- <apex:column headerValue="Includes:"> <apex:outputField value="{!wrapper.acrX.Help_Text__c}"/>  </apex:column> -->


                <apex:column headerValue="Percentage">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.acrX.Percentage__c}" required="false"/> 
                </apex:column>



                            </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

and the result is:

[image]

Is there a way in which I can dynamically change the helptext per row? For example, the helptext in the first row would be 'Kevin de Bryune', for the third row (Arsenal) it would read 'Sanchez' etc.

I can reference formulas with global variables such as:

```
sfdcPage.setHelp('example-title', '{!$User.FirstName}' );
```

However, is there a way I can make the helptext completely dynamic based on the value in the 'Team' column?

Comment: You seem to have missed this part of the blog post: *ensuring to discard the “-_help” from the id*

Comment: You can make `example-title` part dynamic to get the help text. @AdrianLarson Link in your comment is missing.

Comment: The link is *in the OP*...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand? If the row is 'Arsenal', how would I make 'Sanchez' in the help text? My pageBlock is being populated by an output field value reference to the custom controller method.

Comment: My apologies @AdrianLarson, I really need to grab a coffee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came with this example code for you:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="record">
                <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="display: inline-block" labelStyle="display: inline-block; width: 10px;" helpText="{!record.Name}">
                            <apex:outputLabel value="" />
                            <apex:outputField value="{!record.Name}" />
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Percentage">
                    <apex:inputText />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Instead of relying on internal system libraries, you can use the standard apex:pageBlockSectionItem help text to render it as you wish. You'll want to figure out how to apply some styles to avoid the left-side empty space that occurs, but this should get you started.

Edit: Now with apex:pageBlockTable!

Comment: Thanks a lot, @sfdcfox :) But my values are being populated by a pageBlockTable. I'll share more of my code in my edit.

Comment: @AndyHitchings It's just about juggling some tags around. Here's a pageBlockTable version instead.

Comment: @AndyHitchings Go to your Account tab and select All Account in list view filters. After that navigate to page, you should be able to see Account records.

Comment: And what if the helptext is to be some random text which isn't stored anywhere in Salesforce? The values 'Sanchez' etc aren't input anywhere. Also, what if I only want 2 out of the 10 rows with a helptext bubble? Is that possible? I have a wrapper as the custom controller and it includes a custom object and the opportunity object. I have quite a bit of re-rendering on the page based on input fields. And the section with the helptext I'd like is a per the screenshot.

Comment: @AndyHitchings Yes, you could choose if you wanted to render a help text or not, and yes, you can drive your help text off of anything you can put in your wrapper class. This example was meant to be a quick demonstration that anyone could copy and paste into their org and give it a go. This code renders very closely to your screenshot, except for an alignment issue with the bubbles (they're too low on the row for my liking), but the general idea was to give you a framework you could start from.

Comment: Thank you. I can see how the framework is helpful but I don't see how I can choose to have only certain rows have a helptext bubble? I was expecting something like IF(custom_field_a__c = 'A', 'helptext version1', '') to be an option.

Comment: @AndyHitchings I would strongly advise that you calculate the appropriate help text within your wrapper class. Using expressions in VF will very quickly lead to View State governor exceptions, especially in an iterator element. As it is, you'll probably have to do something like `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!item.showHelp}" helpText="...">...</apex:pageBlockSectionItem><apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!not item.showHelp}">...</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>`...

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. After a good night sleep and re-visiting this, i've been able to achieve this such that only rows I want are rendered with helptext.